# Listview setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview of items, each item has some imagesviews and textviews. I've googled many solutions, but none of them helped me. I am very new to android development, I guess I am losing something obvious. I also assume that maybe I've tried too many solutions and they block each other somehow. Please, help me out.
here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private List<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<Lesson>();

private int loop_count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    FillLessonList();
    FillListView();
}
    private void FillListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Lesson> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.i("debug", "item click: " + view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_text_lesson_name));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LessonActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lesson>
{
    MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(MyActivity.this, R.layout.lesson_item, lessons);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View lessonView = convertView;
        if(lessonView == null)
        {
            lessonView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lesson_item, parent, false);
        }

        Lesson currentLesson = lessons.get(position);

        //here I add all the needed info into the item.
        //This part works fine and displays everything I need properly.

        return lessonView;
    }
```

The only thing that is really logged with every click is:

```
05-18 17:10:57.158 29101-29101/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/AbsListView: Touch down: touch mode = 0,mScrollY = 0,y = 122.7923,mFirstPosition = 0,mActivePointerId = 0,mDataChanged = false,adatper size = 15,this = android.widget.ListView{32614ed4 VFED.VC. .F...... 60,0-1020,1599 #7f0d0076 app:id/lessonsList}
    05-18 17:10:57.258 29101-29101/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/AbsListView: CheckForTap:mFirstPosition = 0,mMotionPosition = 0,child = android.widget.RelativeLayout{3506a91f V.E..... ........ 0,0-960,225}
    05-18 17:10:57.293 29101-29101/h2d.drawteam.howtodraw D/AbsListView: Touch up: touch mode = 1,mScrollY = 0,mLastY = -2147483648,mMotionPosition = 0,mFirstPosition = 0,mDataChanged = false,adatper size = 15,this = android.widget.ListView{32614ed4 VFED.VC. .F...... 60,0-1020,1599 #7f0d0076 app:id/lessonsList}
```

Here is my main layout xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_clear"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container_button_back"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button_fit"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/separator_1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container_list"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lessonsList"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my list item xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
    android:minHeight="75dp"
    android:minWidth="75dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/default_lesson_name"
    android:id="@+id/lesson_text_lesson_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lesson_rate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/default_steps"
    android:id="@+id/lesson_text_steps"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lesson_text_lesson_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lesson_rate"
    android:src="@drawable/rate1"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lesson_text_steps"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lesson_separator"
    android:src="@drawable/separator"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lesson_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

Comment: logs are executed on clicks so what exactly is not working?

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" remove this line from listview and try it.Hope it will work.

Comment: @Samstone try toast message also instead of log

Comment: @user1930106 Those are different logs, not connected with my log. You can see it in the message.

Comment: @PradeepGupta This didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dhiraj no changes either.

Comment: Remove `android:clickable="false"` from your item? Also, just a tip: if you try something and it doesn't work, remove the changes and try something else. Otherwise your code will get cluttered.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp you mean from relative layout or from every view in my item including the layout?

Comment: For starters, from your `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp None of that helped anyway. I've set clickable="true" for layout, now when I click on my Item I can see that I clicked it(white text becomes black while my finger is on the item), but still nothing nothing is logged or toasted anyway. In my listener I also start a new activity, and nothing is happening.

Comment: Add your code for your whole `Activity` to your question.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp I've updated my question with code that is somehow connected with my listview.

Comment: I would say => remove all  `android:clickable="false"` from your item.xml

Comment: And `android:focusable="false"` also

Comment: And ` android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` also

Comment: @xAqweRx none of this helped. In other questions with similiar problem the solution was to add focusable=false and focusableInTouchMode=false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 Log.i("debug", "item click: " + view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_text_lesson_name));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LessonActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

or

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("debug", "item click: " + view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_text_lesson_name));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LessonActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Alternate method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View lessonView = convertView;
        if(lessonView == null)
        {
            lessonView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lesson_item, parent, false);
        }

        Lesson currentLesson = lessons.get(position);

        //here I add all the needed info into the item.
        //This part works fine and displays everything I need properly.

        lessonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(""testing123,"testing");
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Your toast message.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, LessonActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

        return lessonView;
    }
```

Comment: Androis Studio had to add AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(), but it's not working anyway. Maybe I have something wrong with my imports?

Comment: @SamStone try my edited answer. If problem exist let me know.

Comment: I somewhy cannot use your nickname to adress you directly. I cannot use your code, the error is "setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.onItemClickListener) in AdapterView cannot be applied to (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)" and IDE does not provide any quick fixes, and I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: @SamStone Is your listview is filled with data.

Comment: Yes it is. It has 15 items, each one displayed the way I want, I can scroll the list. I've added a button to the item to test if it works, and it works. But I need to be able to click on the whole item(I can't make the item to be one big button, there are different elements in it), button is just a part of it.

Comment: @SamStone Try my Alternate method in my edited answer. See in the logcat. If problem exist let me know.

Comment: Wow! Setting the listener inside the getView() override method worked! Thank you Vishwesh!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a custom adapter, you need to have the onClickListener inside of getView(). So if you want some action when user clicks say the ImageView- lesson_icon, then you may want to write something like:

```
lessonView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_icon).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, Vishwesh Jainkuniya solved this earlier. Thank you.